# Setting image to UIImageView in tableview cell makes the scrolling and rotation slow

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I've a UIImageView in my TableViewCell. When i don't set the image, scrolling and the rotation of the UI works very smoothly. But when the images are displayed in the cells, the scrolling and the rotation animation becomes jerky. I've used lazy-loading methods for the images to be displayed in the cells. For displaying the image, I'm maintaining a dictionary of NSData. If the data corresponding to the image is present then i'm just doing

```
cell.Icon=[self imageForCellAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

and the function is like

```
-(UIImage*)imageForCellAtIndex:(int)index
{
  Obj *ob=[mList objectAtIndex:index];
  if([mIcons objectForKey:app.Icon100])
    return [UIImage imageWithData:[mIcons objectForKey:ob.IconLink]];
  else
  {
    [self DownloadIconForIndex:index];
  }
  return nil;
}
```

The property **Icon** for the cell is set like

```
@property(nonatomic,assign)UIImage *AppIcon;
```

and in the cell.m file i'm overriding the setter

```
-(void)setIcon:(UIImage *)icon
{
  iconImageView.image=icon;
}
```

Where i'm going wrong. Please suggest.

Answer (score -1):

Buddy, If you are loading images from URL, then obviously they will load slowly & also make the scroll slower. Use **LazyImageLoading**.

Comment: I've already mentioned in the question that i'm using Lazyloading and explained the logic also.